# java.lang.RuntimeException & java.lang.IllegalStateException error messages

Tags: android

I'm pretty sure the problem started when I added a theme to my app. I made a few changes without saving it so I'm not completely sure.

I keep getting a java runtime error and a message that says I need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendent). How do I do this while keeping my current theme? (Black, no title bar, full screen) I've been learning development for about a week now and I'm lost as to how to resolve this.

```
Android Manifest:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crystalball"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:requiredForAllUsers="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </a`enter code here`ctivity>
    </application>

</manifest>

activity_main.xml: 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.crystalball.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Enlighten me!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a copy of my LogCat:

```
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crystalball/com.example.crystalball.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at com.example.crystalball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
03-20 10:55:27.369: E/AndroidRuntime(19650):    ... 11 more
```

Thank you for anything you can contribute.

Comment: the error message says it all : `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: It turns out it was in the wrong place. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" needed to be under my Activity, but the first time I tried to correct, I put it under Application.